# Does GNU Assembler add its own entry point?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

Say I have the following Assembly code:

```
.section .text

.globl _start
_start:
```

If I created an executable file using the following commands:

```
as 1.s -o 1.o
ld 1.o -o 1
```

Will the GNU Assembler add its own entry point to my executable which calls `_start` or will `_start` be the actual entry point?

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630193/how-to-create-local-variables-inside-the-main-function) for more details.

Comment: I expect the _assembler_ won't, it's not its role. This is a job for the _linker_. When the linker is told to link everything together into an archive/library, it does _not_ introduce a `_start` entry point. On the other hand, when it is told to link an executable, it links in the C runtime (`crt1.o`), that amongst others declares a function `_start`, which is the default entry point. Since you declare it yourself, you'd have to forbid the linker from attempting to link in the C runtime on pain of an error. Alternatively, GNU `ld` lets you choose a different entry point with the `-e` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file crt0.o (or crt1.o or however this file is called) that contains the startup code mentioned in the other question has also been written in assembler.

So what the Linker ("ld") does is to search all object files (which are in fact all created using "as") for a symbol named "_start" which becomes the entry point.

You are of course free to add crt0.o to your assembler-written program when using "ld". In this case however you MUST NOT name your symbol "_start" but "main" in your assembler file:

```
.globl main
.text
main:
    ...
```

Otherwise "ld" will print an error message because it will find two symbols named "_start" and it does not know which one is the entry point!

Answer (score 1):

You can check it this way:

```
objdump -x 1 # n.b. 1 is the name of your program
```

This will print, among other things:

```
start address 0x000000...
```

Take the address it gives you, and search for it elsewhere in the output.  I think you will find it matches the start of the `.text` segment, as well as the `_start` symbol.  If so, then `_start` is indeed the ELF entry point.